# HTML/Javascript Initiate Print with Options?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a image I want to print that I want to be in the top left of the paper and have no margins/borders. Is there some how I can do this? Or is the only option to print an image and that's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to change their printer settings, you cannot change any printing options like that. Sorry.

You are not allowed to know anything about their printer even. (After all, maybe they are printing it on 500 foot by 500 foot paper, and there is plenty of room for margins!)

If you mean you want to change your page, then use CSS.

Comment: Darn it... Well then that will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can print only what you want with the help of CSS. For example:

```
@media screen { /* Version for the screen */
  img.some_class { display:none; }
}
@media print { /* Version for the print */
  img.some_class { display:block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
}
```

But you can not manipulate with printer settings, only with what browser will send to printer.

ps: if I understood you correctly :)

Comment: I read his question same as you at first. But now that I see Simon's answer I see what OP is getting at. He wasn't even talking about CSS!